# TFS 2008 - Build bot defaulting to .net 3.5 instead of .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm having a problem with TFS 2008 trying to compile a .NET 4.0 C# ASP.Net application. It builds without issue locally and the build server is capable of building .NET 4.0 applications, some of the other projects on the server are full .Net 4.0 applications. These build without issues.

My solution upon attempting to build it on TFS, the .Net 3.5 compiler is used. From what I can see the team build project file and solution files don't have anything specifying the use of .net 3.5  These files compared to the existing working .Net 4.0 solution don't show any major differences.

Looking at the build log a quick keyword seach shows that 4.0 is not mentioned in the entire log. The teambuild.proj was created with VS 2008 (MSBuild 3.5) and in the solution both projects are set to .Net 4.0. I can provide build log exerpts but the question is for what areas? (The build log is 1.5 MB, too large to dump out here practically)

Any help would be appreciated thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

In your build definition you should be able to pass in some MSBuild Arguments

(Sorry I don't have TFS 2008 available for a screen shot but have a poke around inside the build definition, I think from memory they are labeled as "MSBuild Command Line Arguments" or something similar)

Override the ToolsVersion by passing in `/ToolsVersion=4.0` as an MSBuild Argument this will force your build process to sue the .net 4.0 tool set.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) goes in to more detail